# Nuget restore fails in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, dnx, dnu

I am trying to go through tutorial on Pluralsight for ASP.NET Core 1.0 Fundamentals from Scott Allen. I am using VS 2015. I created new ASP.NET 5 project with Empty template selected. However, when I try to build I see this error in VS

[image]

My attempt to restore NuGet packages either from VS or from Command Line with DNU provides [this error](http://pastebin.com/gwk7wGjv)

NOTE: I have previously upgraded DNX versions to the latest available

[image]

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: Looking at the exception callstack it looks like DNX is failing to read one of the unzipped .nuspec files. I would take a look at your packages directory `%home%\.dnx\packages` and take a look at the kestrel.https directory and see if the .nuspec is empty, or has some strange characters at the beginning of the file, or has a bad BOM. A brute force fix may be to delete the .dnx\packages directory to force things to be downloaded again. You may be able to get away with deleting just the kestrel NuGet package directories.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your project and run from command line:

```
dnu restore --no-cache
```